# Only the first IF statement out of 3 is executed within a PHP loop

Tags: php, codeigniter, loops, if-statement, iteration

The following code uploads multiple images no problem. However, I'm trying to get it to update a field in a table based on what iteration the loop is in. PROBLEM: The IF Statement seems to not work when looped. I.e. it only adds the first file_name to the database.

Anyone see what I'm doing wrong here? Much appreciated if so!!!

```
for ($i = 1; $i < 4; $i++)
{
  /* Handle the file upload */
  $upload = $this->upload->do_upload('image' . $i);

  /* File failed to upload - continue */
  if ($upload === FALSE)
    continue;

  /* Get the data about the file */
  $data = $this->upload->data();

  $uploadedFiles[$i] = $data;

  if ($i == 1)
  {
    $filenames1 = array(
      'product_image_front' => $data['file_name'],
    );

    $this->db->where('id', $this->db->insert_id());
    $this->db->update('products', $filenames1);
  }

  if ($i == 2)
  {

    $filenames2 = array(
      'product_image_back' => $data['file_name'],
    );

    $this->db->where('id', $this->db->insert_id());
    $this->db->update('products', $filenames2);
  }

  if ($i == 3)
  {

    $filenames3 = array(
      'product_image_back' => $data['file_name'],
    );

    $this->db->where('id', $this->db->insert_id());
    $this->db->update('products', $filenames3);
  }

}
```

Comment: There are 5 if statements, not 3.  What if statement are you referring to?  I would highly recommend refactoring the code to put repeated code in a function or otherwise not have to repeat it.

Comment: Can you put an `echo "hello world"` inside your `$i==2` block to check if it reaches that point? Some tips:

1. Indent your code properly. Everything between curly braces should be indented another level like this: http://pastebin.com/SVFPZ2Tt . It's much more readable. 2. Use an "else if" for `$i==2` and `$i==3`. It's more efficient and cleaner. If $i is 1 you don't want to bother checking for $i==2 and $i==3, the else if ensures that only one is executed.

Comment: Not related, but as far as I can tell, you don't need 3 identical code blocks, `if ($i < 4)` would be sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

insert_id - Get the ID generated *in the last query*.

Store it in a variable before the loop.